# Get value of DropDown at Controller while submitting form MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

This is My View.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("uploadimage",
                           "PatientDocumentsMain",
                            FormMethod.Post,
                            new { @Area = "PatientDocument", enctype = 
                            "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  class="table table-
          striped">
          <tr>
           <td>
              Document Name:<span class="spnError">*</span>
           </td>
           <td>
              <input type="text" id="txtDocumentName" name="DocName" 
                class="required form-control" />
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td class="tdEditDoc">
             <span>Document Type:</span><span class="spnError">*</span>
           </td>
           <td id="tdDocumentCategory">                 
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlDocumentCategory", null, new { @id = "", 
                               @onchange = "AddCategory();", @class = 
                               "required form-control", @name= "DocType" })
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdEditDoc">
              <span>Date:</span><span class="spnError">*</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="txtPatientDocumentDate" class="Date 
              required IsDate form-control" name="DocDate" />
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td class="tdEditDoc" style="height: 25px;">
               <span>Confidental:</span>
             </td>
             <td>
               <input type="checkbox" id="chkPatientDocumentIsConfedential" 
                />
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdEditDoc" style="vertical-align: top">
                Comments:
              </td>
              <td>
                <textarea id="txtPatientDocumentComments" name="comments" 
                style="margin-right: 15px; width: 245px; height: 69px; 
                border-width: 1px; border-color: #c4c4c4;resize:none" 
                class="form-control">
                </textarea>
               </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" title="Upload file(s)" />
}
```

I'm submitting this form to this controller

```
 public void uploadimage(string DocName, string DocType, string DocDate, string d, string comments, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

    }
```

I'm getting all other parameters except DropDown value.Plus How can I get Value of checkbox(Checked or not). I'm not using any model and want to do without it.

Comment: Why you are creating so much variables within your post actionMethod, I would suggest using FormValues or Model.

Comment: can't use model. How can I use FormValues?

Comment: Replace your parameters within ActionMethod with 
 `public void uploadImage(FormCollection fomr)... `Its a key/value dictionary.

Comment: @AravindSivam Thanks bro! Working now so I was rewriting name attribute.

Comment: Your `<select>` has `name="ddlDocumentCategory"` which has no relationship to the parameters in your POST method. Stop generating your html manually and use a model (that's what the `M` in MVC stands for) and bind to you model using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods (and the parameter in your POST method will be your model)

Comment: Html.DropDownList("DocType", null, new { id = "", onchange = "AddCategory();", class = "required form-control" })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parameter is the name of field

```
@Html.DropDownList("DocType", null, new { @id = "", @onchange = "AddCategory();", @class = "required form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown bind with null value ?

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlDocumentCategory", null, new { @id = "", @onchange = "AddCategory();", @class = "required form-control", @name= "DocType" })
```

Also make sure name of input fields same as string parameter.

Helpful link
[How to submit your form in asp.net mvc](https://techfunda.com/howto/asp-net-mvc/controller)

Comment: `@name= "DocType"` does nothing at all fortunately (it does not change the `name` attribute)

Comment: Well he doesnt bind value to dropdown , second name of input must be same of receving parmater (<input type="checkbox" name="status" id="check" />) now get the value of checkbox by using parameter  of 'string status' and i also  have reffer link , how to post form to asp.net mvc

Comment: i'm binding dropdown with Viewbag.ddlDocumentCategory. But that was not my question. I was unable to get value at controller and it was due to conflicting name attribute.